# How to create a graph for IdealGraphVisualizer?

Tags: java, jvm, virtual-machine, java-11

I used OpenJDK v11.0.0.1 and v17. When i try to use command in cmd (Windows 7):

e:\Java\OpenJDK_17.0.9\jdk-17.0.9+9\bin\java -Xbatch -XX:PrintIdealGraphFile=5.xml AutoHandler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

I show error: VM option "PrintIdealGraphFile" is notproduct and is available only in debug version of VM.

I searched on the Internet for what parameters I could use, but all actions led to this error.

[image]

Comment: How does “*is available only in debug version*” create the impression that you can find some parameters in the internet that will make the feature somehow available in your non-debug version?

Comment: Your comment helped me see the situation from a different perspective.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that I should take the OpenJDK source code (the version I need) and convert it in some way so that the result is not a realese version of java.exe, but a debug version, right?

Comment: The JVM is contained in the `jvm.dll` file but otherwise, yes, you have to create a debug build as described in [this document](https://openjdk.org/groups/build/doc/building.html). I don’t know if you can find prebuilt debug binaries somewhere in the internet.

Comment: [builds.shipilev.net](https://builds.shipilev.net/) has debug JVM builds.